# Get Form data from html on page refresh(php)

Tags: php, javascript, hidden-field

I ran into a little problem with my college project again :(

```
<input type="text" name="timrem" value="" />
```

This is a hidden field that I want the data from.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['timrem']))
{
    $tim=$_REQUEST['timrem'];
}
```

This is the code used to get the value from `timrem`.
The variable timrem is used to initialize a countdown sequence on the page(implemented using javascript)

```
<span id="countdown-1" style="float:right"><?php echo $tim;?>
```

The value of the hidden field is dynamically changed via java script counter implemented.

```
sremtime=(parseInt(minRemain*60)) + (parseInt(secsRemain));
document.frmTest.timrem.value=sremtime;
```

this works fine when the page is submitted, ie, the time doesn't restart from the next page. But when the page is refreshed, the timer is restarted to the value of the `$tim` when the timer first started.

Is it possible to somehow get the value of the hidden input on page refresh?

And also, please comment on the approach taken to preserve the time elapsed to the next page. This is a project on online examination.

Comment: Try to avoid html inside your question, specially if you need to highlight code block, you can use 4 spaces (check my edit).

Comment: @j0k will keep that in mind :) sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need your variable to persist across refreshes, you cannot rely on information passed back from client to server. The only information you can rely on is the information passed with the very first request, and that obviously doesn't include your time. The best solution I can think of is to store your timestamp in a session variable on the server:

```
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['timrem'])) $_SESSION['timrem'] = time(); // set this if it is the first time this page is loaded
$tim = time() - $_SESSION['timrem']; // $tim is now the number of seconds since the page was first loaded in this session
```

You do not need to pass the time back and forth between client and server to keep track of it, although your javascript will probably need it.

Comment: Thanks :)
This might be a possible solution. Will get back after trying :) couple of minutes.

Comment: umm, how to add line breaks here? return ky doesn't seem to cut it here :P

Comment: I will need to unset the session on a fresh page load, i suppose

Comment: When your time runs out, you call a new page, and that page should unset the `timrem` session variable.

Comment: 'if(empty($_SESSION['starttime']))
{
 $_SESSION['starttime'] = time();
 $timer=10*60;
}
else{
 $timelapsed = time() - $_SESSION['starttime'];
 $timer=$timer-$timelapsed;
}'

Comment: will this get me the correct value needed?
10*60 is 10 minutes in seconds

Comment: Solved :)
got the elapsed time from your code. subtracted from my time that was needed. then used that variable as timer :)
Appreciate all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

A good idea might be storing a timestamp either in your PHP page or in a database (for multiple users), and use it to generate $tim. Passing data on refresh doesn't seem possible as there is no request triggered.

Comment: Thank for replying.
Storing a timestamp and comparing it with current time in php?
That was one of my options,but I also need to generate the timer that is displayed onscreen. 
Is that possible with a timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

How about you store a "target time" (what ever time remaining is counting down to) in your url. you could even store it in epoch time:

```
myurl.com/stuff.html?target_time=1359553896
```

that way when the page is refreshed you still have it with you and you can calculate time remaining from that. if you don't want it in your url, you could probably hide it on the page somewhere with a `display:none` style.

how about something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/QpZcV/1/

Comment: Thank you.
I am sorry, i am unable to understand. how will the target_time be set in the url?
I am counting from 180 minutes to 0, then a page call is triggered.
I need to display it in real time using java script too.

Comment: keep in mind that you could also store it on the page, and the more I think about it I might go this way. when does the timer get set? on what event? when the user first navigates to the page? i'll try to make a jsfiddle real quick to show you what I mean.

Comment: Here is the scenario,

A user logs in to give the examination->Reads the instructions -> Clicks the Start Button(submit type) and the timer is set. then goes on till 0 or the number of questions reach 105.

Comment: thanks, yeah as long as you also store this on the server side and write the epoch time into the hidden div, the jsfiddle i just made should do the trick

Comment: it is displaying in the jsfiddle, but when implemented I am unable to see the time.

Comment: so, the time is statically just in the html and you have to pretend to be php for jsfiddle an write in the time stamp you want. you did want a count down right?